# Strange std::map behavior

Tags: c++, pointers, std, stdmap

I have a question about map from the STL.
I have my class Element:

```
class Element {

   Element();
   uint16_t getId(void);

   private:
     uint16_t myId;

}
```

into the class `ManagerClass` i have a `std::map<uint16_t, Element> myMAP` and this method:

```
void loadElement() {
   std::vector<Element> theVector = ConfigManager::getInstance().load();

   for(unsigned i = 0; i< theVector.size(); i++) {
      Element el = theVector.at(i);
      myMAP.insert(myElementPair(element.getId(), element));
   }
}
```

In another method of ManagerClass I have a crash when I skim my data structure myMAP:

```
void read() {

   std::map<uint16_t,Element>::iterator it;
   for(it=myMAP.begin(); it != myMAP.end(); ++it) {
      std::cout << "The ID: " << it->first << std::endl;
   }
}
```

I had the crash on the second element (myMAP contains 2 elements) and the first print has strange value of ID.
Can you suggest what's the problem?
When I insert an element in this way, will the `std::map` will make a copy of element?

Comment: Does Element have any dynamically allocated members in the actual code? As this would not compile (unti_16t).

Comment: what does `myElementPair` look like? is it anything like `std::make_pair(element.getId(), element)` ? try `myMAP.insert(std::make_pair(element.getId(), element));`

Comment: Sorry is the uint16_t!!

Comment: `Element el = theVector.at(i);
      myMAP.insert(myElementPair(element.getId(), element));` makes *no* sense. Post some *real* code if you want a *real* answer!

Comment: myElementPair is defined in this way: typedef std::pair<uint16_t, Element>

Comment: @GgSalent, fine, but where's `element` come from?

Comment: Each element is built when I call ConfigManager::getInstance().load() (ConfigManager is a singleton).
I build with its constructor and then use push_back the vector

Comment: Do you really have a requirement that your code runs **only** on systems that have an unsigned type that holds **exactly** 16 bits? `uint_least16_t` is more flexible, and `unsigned short` is even better.

Answer (score 0):

I realize you gave a snippet of code, but there's something that looks suspicious - why not try this instead?

```
void loadElement() {
  std::vector<Element> theVector = ConfigManager::getInstance().load();

  for(unsigned i = 0; i< theVector.size(); i++) {
    // Use the el local variable instead of "element"
    Element& el = theVector.at(i);
    // Use operator[] instead - does a look up and 
    // creates element automagically.
    myMAP[el.getId()] = el;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(unsigned i = 0; i< theVector.size(); i++) 
{
   Element el = theVector.at(i);
   myMAP.insert(myElementPair(element.getId(), element));
}
```

I think you meant to insert `el`, not `element`?

```
  myMAP.insert(myElementPair(el.getId(), el));
```